# Chaining underscore.js in node.js throws 'Invalid REPL keyword'

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, hoisting

I'm a n00b at using underscore/node and am trying to understand the concept of chaining functions. However, I cannot elicit proper outputs when trying to chain functions in node. Grabbing the example snipp from underscore's chaining section produces 'Invalid REPL keyword':

```
var __ = require("underscore"); //for underscore use in node

var lyrics = [
  {line: 1, words: "I'm a lumberjack and I'm okay"},
  {line: 2, words: "I sleep all night and I work all day"},
  {line: 3, words: "He's a lumberjack and he's okay"},
  {line: 4, words: "He sleeps all night and he works all day"}
];

__.chain(lyrics) //in the console chain appears to run and return correctly, but then
  .map(function(line) { return line.words.split(' '); }) //Invalid REPL keyword
  .flatten()                                             //Invalid REPL keyword
  .reduce(function(counts, word) { 
    counts[word] = (counts[word] || 0) + 1;
    return counts;
  }, {})                                                 //Invalid REPL keyword
  .value();                                              //Invalid REPL keyword
```

Am I a victim of [ASI](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.9.1) in this case? If so where is the ';' trying to be inserted? I am confused since plugging this snippet into JSHint produces no errors. Can one of you please help me identify the error?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running this by pasting it into a node prompt? You should have it in its own file and run `node file.js`.

Comment: Interesting, I get an output running it the way you suggested. Curious though, why would it not throw any errors by just being in its own file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess in a way you are running into ASI in that generally semicolons are inserted to separate expressions. In a more general sense though, what you are doing is typing into Node's [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) (what you get when you run `node` with no args), and in a REPL environment, if a line can be executed on its own, it will and its result will be printed out.

This is different from a standard JS environment, which will fully process an entire function/file before executing it.

The error you are getting, `Invalid REPL keyword`, is because Node's REPL has a set of commands that all begin with `.`, such as `.clear` ([the full list is here](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl_features)), and `.map` and such are JS functions, not REPL commands.

So for example if I take your example and reorder the `.`s to the end of the line (so that each line can't be processed on its own), it will work in the REPL:

```
var __ = require("underscore"); //for underscore use in node

var lyrics = [
  {line: 1, words: "I'm a lumberjack and I'm okay"},
  {line: 2, words: "I sleep all night and I work all day"},
  {line: 3, words: "He's a lumberjack and he's okay"},
  {line: 4, words: "He sleeps all night and he works all day"}
];

__.chain(lyrics).
  map(function(line) {
    return line.words.split(' ');
  }).
  flatten().
  reduce(function(counts, word) { 
    counts[word] = (counts[word] || 0) + 1;
    return counts;
  }, {}).
  value();
```

Really though, the only time you should be using the REPL is for quick tests, where the single-line behavior is usually helpful. When doing normal development, you should work in a file and run `node <filename>` to test your code.

Comment: Seems to me that there would be nothing wrong with using the REPL for development if problems like this were cleaned up.

Comment: @NateC-K Cleaned up how exactly? I don't see any way avoid an issue like this without introducing other restrictions.

Comment: I don't know what the best way to fix it would be. However, having an REPL that doesn't work with valid source code in the language it's supposed to support seems self-defeating. One possibility is to require some control sequence to put the REPL into a mode where it accepts special commands, instead of the dot syntax for commands. Some Lisp interpreters do this, and Erlang. It could be enabled by a command line switch with the old syntax enabled by default for backward compatibility.

Comment: @NateC-K StackOverflow really isn't a good place for discussions. Feel free to email me if want to continue chatting about this. You are right that the REPL could potentially be improved, so I guess it's mostly a question of priority and importance.